# Ruby on Rails pgsql ambiguous column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my rails application I have the  following query:

```
School.joins(:student, student: :student_info).where("lower(name) like ? or lower(student_info.name) like ?", paramsfo[:search].downcase, params[:search].downcase)
```

As you can see I have two columns named name in two tables and postgresql is complaining column name is ambiguous. How do I solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Try `lower(schools.name) like ? or lower(student_info.name) like ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove ambiguity, you should use table name with both column names.

```
lower(schools.name) like ? or lower(student_info.name) like ?
```